# Python integer prefix range algorithm

Tags: python, regex, type-conversion

Here is my problem. I have various integer inputs varying in length, but I only want certain number prefixes to be printed. The prefix ranges are 20000-20150 all five digits. So far I have:

```
print 20000 <= prefix <= 20150
```

which is fine, but how do I find or capture the prefix  '20000' in the number using Python.

example:20000201501

using the code below won't work, in such cases because there are two instances where the value of prefix is present, I only want the first prefix.

```
obj = 20000201501
if prefix in obj
    print prefix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply:

```
>>> num = 20000201501
>>> print int(str(num)[:5])
20000
```

So, you need something like this:

```
def prefix(num):
    return int(str(num)[:5])

print 20000 < prefix(20000201501) < 20150
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the object a string (using `str`), slice the first 5 characters off of it (as the prefix) and then convert that back to an integer (using `int`):

```
 prefix = int(str(obj)[:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def valid_prefix(number):
    return 20000 <= int(number) <= 20150

#obj is string:
obj = "20000201501"
print valid_prefix(obj[:5])

#obj is number:
obj = 20000201501
print valid_prefix(str(obj)[:5])
```